# Find average of collection of TimeSpans

Tags: c#, average, timespan

I have collection of TimeSpans, they represent time spent doing a task. Now I would like to find the average time spent on that task. It should be easy but for some reason I'm not getting the correct average.

Here's my code:

```
private TimeSpan? GetTimeSpanAverage(List<TimeSpan> sourceList)
{
    TimeSpan total = default(TimeSpan);

    var sortedDates = sourceList.OrderBy(x => x);

    foreach (var dateTime in sortedDates)
    {
        total += dateTime;
    }
    return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(total.TotalMilliseconds/sortedDates.Count());
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and what result you are getting and what result you are expecting. BTW: The ordering is not necessary.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can use the [Average overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339733(v=vs.90).aspx) that takes a collection of long in parameter:

```
double doubleAverageTicks = sourceList.Average(timeSpan => timeSpan.Ticks);
long longAverageTicks = Convert.ToInt64(doubleAverageTicks);

return new TimeSpan(longAverageTicks);
```

Comment: This gives me a error: cannot convert from 'double' to 'long'

Comment: Instead of Ticks you can also use `TotalSeconds` and then use `TimeSpan.FromSeconds`

Comment: @V4Vendetta Yes you can but you'll loose the sub second components which can be useful if your are timing short actions

Comment: @vc74 Well in that case you can have TotalMilliseconds, also in your case you are casting double to long so the loss is happening in this case too :)

Comment: @V4Vendetta Yes but only once the average has been calculated which is better than for every timespan.

Answer (score 12):

```
var average = new TimeSpan(sourceList.Select(ts => ts.Ticks).Average());
```

---

Note, your method returns a [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx), but doesn't need to, unless you want to return null if the source list is empty, in which case just do a separate check first.

Comment: There is no `Enumerable.Average()` overload that returns `long` value, as well as there is no TimeSpan constructor that accept double as the argument, so the example is not building for me. To make it compile I was forced to add an explicit cast `(long)` of the argument: `var average = new TimeSpan((long)sourceList.Select(ts => ts.Ticks).Average());`

Answer (score 4):

In Addition to the above answer, I would suggest you take an average on the Seconds or MilliSeconds level (depending on what you require)

```
sourceList.Average(timeSpan => timeSpan.ToTalMilliseconds)
```

Now using this value you could arrive at the new TimeSpan using

```
TimeSpan avg = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(double value here)
```

Comment: I just want to warn everyone that if your average is not even one millisecond, than because of [some precision problems](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5450832/1108200) your new average `TimeSpan` will be always 0.

Comment: @Artholl That was my exact problem