# C# Time Average

Tags: c#, list, time, average

How Can I calculate the average of a given List which content is described below:

```
06:56
06:58
06:55
06:54
06:54
06:53
06:55
06:53
06:58
06:54
06:58
06:55
06:54
06:50
06:54
06:57
```

Any idea ?!?

Comment: How is this list declared? Which `Type`?

Comment: In C# with one line of code, don't refrain to post it and we will try to help you if something doesn't work with that...

Comment: Convert it to a decimal (whole hours, fractional minutes) and then average that.

Comment: It's just a list that contains a bunch of hour entries in DateTime format.

Comment: Parse them into a TimeSpan. Then find the averages of the total seconds of the TimeSpans.

Comment: Why so cruel guys? He asked a second question here...

Comment: Yes, neither do I get it. But thanks for taking the time for the detailed solution.

Answer (score 9):

```
        var times = new List<string>
        {
            "06:56",
            "06:58",
            "06:55",
            "06:54",
            "06:54",
            "06:53",
            "06:55",
            "06:53",
            "06:58",
            "06:54",
            "06:58",
            "06:55",
            "06:54",
            "06:50",
            "06:54",
            "06:57"
        };
        var average = times
            .Select(TimeSpan.Parse)
            .Average(x => x.TotalMilliseconds);

        var averageTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(average);
```

Comment: There is a variation here: [Find average of collection of timespans] http://stackoverflow.com/a/8847711/3527297 which averages on the ticks which (though not for the sample data here) may offer a higher precision for subsecond values.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the values to *TimeSpan*. The you can average directly with the output as the correct data type.

**Addendum**

Adding to the answer from @gabba providing a list of strings and the link above using ticks, you can calculate the average this way:

```
TimeSpan average = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt64(times.Average(x => TimeSpan.Parse(x).Ticks)));
```

The result value is, of course, the same: 06:54:52.500

Comment: Thank you folks! I'm gonna try something you suggested.