# TimeSpan c# returns wrong value

Tags: c#

TimeSpan in c# is ignoring values after decimals. How to get exact conversion value?

```
TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5.25).TotalSeconds returns 0.005 instead of 0.00525
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TimeSpan comparison with millisecond precision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571898/timespan-comparison-with-millisecond-precision)

Comment: TimeSpan does not support partial microsecond resolution in your context and will round. You would need to work with _ticks_ and deal with the actual numbers yourself

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.frommilliseconds(v=vs.110).aspx) tells that

> Therefore, value will only be considered accurate to the nearest
>   millisecond.